# Need to update the unpaid_amt in the savings table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my  amounts table:

```
Accountnumber    yearquarter     savingstype    unpaid_amt  statustype
101               20091             mas           -200           w
101               20091             mas            220           p
```

Here in this savings table whenever there is statustype type called 'w' within that Accountnumber,yearquarter,savingstype the status other than 'w' should be updated with the sum
within that Accountnumber,yearquarter,savingstype we need to update the each and every  unpaid_amt in savingstype for 'w' statustype's as "ZERO"

consider the account number 101 : In that savingstype mas it has a status called 'w' and sum of unpaid _amt is "twenty" so we need to make un paid amt ashown below:

```
Accountnumber    yearquarter     savingstype    unpaid_amt  statustype
101               20091             mas              0           w
101               20091             mas             20           p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cte` (to calculate the total unpaid_amt for the group) to `update`.

```
with to_update as (select t.*
                   ,sum(unpaid_amt) over(partition by Accountnumber,yearquarter,savingstype) as total_unpaid
                   from tbl t
                  ) 
update to_update
set unpaid_amt=case when statustype='w' then 0 else total_unpaid end
```

Comment: it is making entire unpaid_amt as 20 but  should have 20 where statustype not equal to w